# Display unescaped HTML String in Django Admin change list

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, escaping

I am currently facing a serious problem.
I use the standard django admin interface incl. change list to display one of my models.
The model has got a field, which includes a link (e.g. in database: http://localhost:8000/data/somefile.pdf'>link).

What I want now is that this string is rendered unescaped and displayed as link. I already tried the following in "change_list_results.html":

```
{% for result in results %}
<tr id="{{ result.1|adminfilter }}" class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
    {% for item in result %}
        {{ item|safe }}
    {% endfor %}</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I used "|safe" on the actual item that is output. Furthermore i tried "{% autoescape off %}". Same result, the String got escaped.

Do you see any other way to get the String displayed unescaped?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to set `allow_tags=True` on your method. It's a bit hidden, but it is described in the documentation - about a screen or so down from where [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) takes you.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the hint. I had to define a method in the model which returns the link and mark this method.allow_tags = True.

Comment: Because the link, answer still correct. But `allow_tags` is deprecated in Django 1.9. Use `format_html()` instead: `Deprecated since version 1.9:
In older versions, you could add an allow_tags attribute to the method to prevent auto-escaping. This attribute is deprecated as it’s safer to use format_html(), format_html_join(), or mark_safe() instead.`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display